# Oracle SQL exlusion constraint

Tags: oracle

I am looking for an Oracle constraint that will exlude all rows in a table that have already been updated for a given year. For example, a given Id field of "123456789_2019_blah" includes the year 2019 as part of the Id. Each day a query will check the table to see if a given year is missing in the Id, such as the year 2020 in "123456789_2020_blah". If 2020 does not exist, a second row will be inserted with the value "123456789_2020_blah"

```
-----------------------
Id
-----------------------
1: 123456789_2019_blah
2: 123456789_2020_blah
```

Going forward, any other time the query runs it should never return rows for Id "123456789_2019_blah" or "123456789_2020_blah". The following year will repeat with 2021, etc. (Assume that field Id is the only field available for the constraint)

I tried using REGEXP_INSTR to check its length but this still returns the 2019 row because there will always be one true result. I also tried group by having with the same result.

```
where (REGEXP_INSTR(Id,'*_2019_*') > 0 and REGEXP_INSTR(Id,'*_2020_*') = 0)
```

Comment: If the year portion of your string has meaning (as it obviously does), then it should be stored in a separate column, not as a substring within something else. Read about "first normal form" if you are not familiar with it. Fix your data model, then a lot of things will become much simpler.

Comment: This is a vendors data model and the scheme cannot be altered.

Comment: :-) I would suggest finding a different vendor, but I know that's asking too much...

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create a function that returns 0 if the latest year does not exist.

```
Return 0 if the latest year does not exist
REGEXP_INSTR(name,'*_' || i_year || '_*') > 0
```